# How to set curl.cainfo=<dir> php.ini in GitHub Actions

Tags: php, curl, github-actions, php-curl, symfony5

I'm using the curl-ext in a Symfony project to make calls to an API over https. In order for curl to work over https it needs a 'cacert.pem' file set in the php.ini file `curl.cainfo = C:\PHP7\...\cacert.pem`

How do I go about doing this in GitHub Actions, given I'm using a default PHP workflow?